# complete.cases does not return required result

Tags: r

I am new in this language and experiment with codes. I am trying to write a code that reads csvs in a folder and calculates/prints the number of complete observations per file (complete rows without NAs). I wrote this code:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {

positivematch <- NULL

setwd(file.path("c:/Rpro/",directory))

for (i in id) {
    filer <- paste(sprintf("%03d", as.numeric(i)), ".csv", sep="")
    filed <- read.csv(filer)
    calc <- complete.cases(filed)
    positivematch[i] <- sum(calc == TRUE)
    }


out <- data.frame(id = id, nobs = positivematch)
return(out)
}
```

The output I get is:

```
  id nobs
1  3   NA
2  3   NA
3  3  243
```

Instead of

```
  id nobs
3  3  243
```

can you help please.

Comment: Are you running it with just `id=3`? WHen you run `positivematch[i]<-sum(calc==TRUE)` when `i=3` and the result of the vector null, you are creating empty values at positions 1 and 2 (you can't have a position three without two before it). So `positivematch` has length 3. When you create your data.frame, R will recycle vectors to a common length so the id gets repeated for each value of `positivematch`. So `complete.cases()` works just find, you are just building your `positivematch` vector incorrectly.

Comment: Yes. The execution was 

complete("specdata", 3)